# Collection of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have some sets $A_1,A_2,...A_N$. I want to "regroup" these sets in a unique "object". This object however should be such that $A_1,A_2,...A_N$ are treated as "separate" elements.

I guess that $\mathcal{A}\equiv \{A_1,A_2,...,A_N\}$ is not what I want because if $A_1=A_2$ then   $\{A_1,A_2,...,A_N\}$ is the same thing as $\{A_2,...,A_N\}$, right?

Which mathematical object allows me to avoid that?

Comment: A sequence...??

Comment: And the notation is still $\{A_1,...,A_N\}$?

Comment: No. But you clearly seem to care about the indexing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Comment: @bounceback In terms of notation, can I write: "consider the multiset $\mathcal{A}\equiv \{A_1,...,A_N\}$"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila what is the correct notation for the sequence object that you suggest? Thanks

Comment: Formally, a sequence is a function from a subset of the natural numbers of the form $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ or the natural numbers or the integers to a set of possible outputs.  It is often informally notated as $\langle A_n\rangle$ or $(A_n)_n$ or as $(A_1,A_2,\dots,A_N)$ or as $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_N$ or as several others.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Formal_definition

Comment: Thanks. Pros and cons of sequence versus multiset?

Comment: @TEX I would use $=$ rather than $\equiv$, but otherwise yes. 
Choosing the best data structure depends entirely on what you mean to do with it.

Comment: The standard trick for duplicating sets is to take their Cartesian product with their index. So replace $A_n$ with the pair $(A_n, n)$. Then even if all the $A_n$'s are equal you'll still end up with distinct "copies" of the set.

Comment: Differing notations are preferred by different authors. But if  you say "The sequence $A_1,...,A_n$" or "The sequence $(A_j)_{j=1}^n$"  it will be understood that you are considering a function $f$ with domain $\{x\in \Bbb N:x\le n\}$  for which you prefer to write $A_j$  for $f(j)$, as this is standard usage, and conforms to the Set-Theoretic definition of a sequence.